# Get the selected value from API JQuery

Tags: jquery, json

I have this dropdown and I'm trying to get the API value and select the value that corresponds to it but it always selects the first option.

How can I get the correct value/text of the option to the dropdown from API?

The dropdown from the view:

```
<select class="form-control select2" data-toggle="select2" id="Status" name="Status"></select>
```

API:

```
"Success": true,
"Message": "",
"Statuses": [
    {
        "Id": 1,
        "Name": "Nuevo"
    },
    {
        "Id": 2,
        "Name": "Leído"
    },
    {
        "Id": 3,
        "Name": "Atendido"
    }
]
```

The dropdown is filled with the values from the API and I have a grid where I have to update the status of the data, and when selecting, it must bring the value it has from the api

Function to get all the status:

```
function LoadMailboxStatus() {
    var dropDown = $("#Status");
    dropDown.empty();

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Mailbox/GetStatuses/",
        error: (result) => $.Notification.error(result),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.Success) {
                var status = result.Statuses;
                $.each(status, function (key, item) {
                    dropDown.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', item.Id).text(item.Name));
                    $('option', this).each(function () {
                        if ($(this).html() == item.Name) {
                            $(this).attr('selected', 'selected')
                        };
                    });
                })
            }
            else {
                $.Notification.error(result.Message);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Functions to get all the values from the another API to Edit the status with the previous API:

```
$dataTable.on("click", "a.edit", function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Mailbox/GetMailboxById/" + $this.data('id'),
        error: (result) => $.Notification.error(result),
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.Success) {
                var mymailbox = result.Mailboxes[0];
                $(FormMB.Id).val(mymailbox.Id);
                $(FormMB.MailboxStatus).val(mymailbox.MailboxStatus);
                LoadMailboxStatus();
            }
            else {
                $.Notification.error(result.Message);
            }
        }
    });

    $mailboxModal.modal();
});
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking?

Comment: `var status = result.Statuses;` should be `var status = result. statuses;`

Comment: @hoangdv yes, but in Postman, is `statuses`

Comment: @victcdva The problem solved? Right?

Comment: @akaBase just get the selected value from the dropdown in the view, the view is filled with the API but always take the status like: value 0 when I do the POST

Comment: @hoangdv nope, that is not the problem

Comment: @victcdva your api returns `statuses` but in your code, you use `Statuses`, the api returns `name`, and you use `Name` ..... Why you alway take first letter uppercase?

Comment: @hoangdv 'cause I build the API from the DTOs and the some way, it convert the first letter in lowercase

Comment: @hoangdv but I repeat, that is not the problem, THE PROBLEM is when I do the POST, it always take the value like 0

Comment: Check the generated `<option>` tags have the correct `Id` values set to the `value` attributes using the inspector (F12 to open and inspect the DOM) and for good measure print out the response to the console to make sure it is what you are expecting

Comment: You said, "_THE PROBLEM is when I do the POST, it always take the value like 0 _" what is "it" here? and which post url are you referring to?

Comment: @palaѕн when the view does the request `url: "/Mailbox/GetMailboxById/" + $this.data('id')` , it must bring me the correct value selected from the API but always takes the first one option

Comment: @palaѕн by I just updated the question, your previous point was fixed

Comment: you have a tbale, and on edit row , you show a dropdown of statuses ,you are using select2 for status dropdown, and  mymailbox.MailboxStatus  is the value you want to get selected from the api drowdown list. right? just to make sure before posting any answer, because your question is a bit confusing. especially the nested loop logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass value you want to select to LoadMailboxStatus method

```
$dataTable.on("click", "a.edit", function () {
//...
$(FormMB.Id).val(mymailbox.Id);
$(FormMB.MailboxStatus).val(mymailbox.MailboxStatus);

//change here
//LoadMailboxStatus();
LoadMailboxStatus(mymailbox.MailboxStatus);
//....
```

and:

```
function LoadMailboxStatus(selectedName) {
    var dropDown = $("#Status");
    dropDown.empty();

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Mailbox/GetStatuses/",
        error: (result) => $.Notification.error(result),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.Success) {
                var status = result.Statuses;
                $.each(status, function (key, item) {
     dropDown.append($('<option></option>').attr('selected',(item.Name == selectedName) ? 'selected' : undefined).attr('value', item.Id).text(item.Name));

/*
                    dropDown.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', item.Id).text(item.Name));
                    $('option', this).each(function () {
                        if ($(this).html() == item.Name) {
                            $(this).attr('selected', 'selected')
                        };
                    });
*/
                })
            }
            else {
                $.Notification.error(result.Message);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is with `this`:

```js
const dropDown = $("#Status")
dropDown.empty()

const Statuses = [
  { "Id": 1, "Name": "Nuevo"    },
  { "Id": 2, "Name": "Leído"    },
  { "Id": 3, "Name": "Atendido" },
]

$.each(Statuses, function (key, item) {
  dropDown.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', item.Id).text(item.Name))
  console.log("wrong this",  this)
  console.log("no <option>'s found", $('option', this).length)
  console.log("<option>'s found with correct this", $('option', dropDown).length)
  // should be $('option', dropDown), but let it be for now
  $('option', this).each(function () {
    console.log("never called!!!")
    // ...
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="form-control select2" data-toggle="select2" id="Status" name="Status"></select>
```

Let's try again with correct `this`

```js
const dropDown = $("#Status")
dropDown.empty()

const Statuses = [
  { "Id": 1, "Name": "Nuevo"    },
  { "Id": 2, "Name": "Leído"    },
  { "Id": 3, "Name": "Atendido" },
]

$.each(Statuses, function (key, item) {
  dropDown.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', item.Id).text(item.Name))
  $('option', dropDown).each(function (i, el) {
    console.log("condition =", $(this).html() == item.Name)
    console.log("tring to select", $(this).html(), i)
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="form-control select2" data-toggle="select2" id="Status" name="Status"></select>
```

So what exactly are you trying to select? Right now your are trying to select **the last** the options in sequence, and you are doing it thrice. (But of cause your original code never gets to this point)

Should be:

```js
const dropDown = $("#Status")
dropDown.empty()

const Statuses = [
  { "Id": 1, "Name": "Nuevo"    },
  { "Id": 2, "Name": "Leído"    },
  { "Id": 3, "Name": "Atendido" },
]

// some condition you must choose by yourself
function condition(item) { return item.Id === 2 }

$.each(Statuses, function (key, item) {
  const option = $('<option></option>').attr('value', item.Id).text(item.Name)
  dropDown.append(option)
  if(condition(item)) option.attr('selected', 'selected')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="form-control select2" data-toggle="select2" id="Status" name="Status"></select>
```

Comment: The value is not selected yet

Comment: Is this a question or just confirmation that everything is fine now?

Comment: nope, when I implement what you put in, the value is not selected

Comment: What value? As you can see in the last code snippet `Leido` (the value I decided to select) is successfully selected. As I said, in your code there is nothing about the value you want to choose. More precisely, the condition you've wrote `if ($(this).html() == item.Name) {` does nothing - it is always true.

Comment: ...always true for the **last** added `<option>`. Updated the second snippet to show it

Comment: And if you've **implemented** and not **copied** the code I've posted, then you probably should update your question with a new version of your code.